# How can I add multiple divs or fieldsets to a zend_form using decorators?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

I'm trying to generate this html hierarchy in my zend_form display group:

```
    <div class="settings">
     <div class="dashed-outline"> //want to add this div
       <fieldset disabledefaultdecorators="1" id="fieldset-settings">
          <legend>Cards</legend>
          </fieldset>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

This is what I have currently:

```
    <div class="settings">
       <fieldset disabledefaultdecorators="1" id="fieldset-settings">
          <legend>Cards</legend>
          </fieldset>
    </div>
```

And this is the code for the above:

```
    $form->addDisplayGroup($flashcardGroup,
                           'settings',
                            array(
                                'legend' => 'Cards',
                                'disableDefaultDecorators' => true,
                                'decorators' => array(
                                                    'FormElements',
                                                    'Fieldset',
                                                     array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'div',  'class' => 'settings')),  
                                                    )
                                )
                            );
```

How do I add the extra div in here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the same decorator twice in Zend_Form, you can pass `array(array('alias'=>'Decorator'), $options)` using the `setDecorators` array syntax.  Also, you shouldn't need to use `disableDefaultDecorators` if you are passing a `decorators` option

```
$form->addDisplayGroup($flashcardGroup,
  'settings',
  array(
    'legend' => 'Cards',
    'decorators' => array(
      'FormElements',
      'Fieldset',
      // need to alias the HtmlTag decorator so you can use it twice
      array(array('Dashed'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'div', 'class'=>'dashed-outline')),
      array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'div',  'class' => 'settings')),  
    )
  )
);
```